# I'm trying to get page source with selenium, but it doesn't work in centos

Tags: java, selenium, centos

goals:get the page source of an dynamic load page;
method:java + selenium + gecokdriver;
problem:in Windows, everything works fine. but when I deploy it in Centos. the result is not what I expected;

I was tring to deploy the crawler code from local machine to a centos7 server.
(the code work fine on my computer.)
but when I depoly it in Centos server, and of course reconfig the related info--firefox.bin + gecokdriver.sh. the source page I get seems the pagecode before it gets render.

```
// the page url I want
String url = "http://rd.huangpuqu.sh.cn/website/html/shprd/shprd_ztrd_cwh/List/list_1.htm"


// Crawler code 
public class MyCrawlerUtils {

    private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyCrawlerUtils.class);

    public static Document getOriginalPage(String url) {
        // 设置浏览器使用的本地驱动
        String firefoxDriver = Global.getConfig("firefox.driver");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",firefoxDriver); // 0.24.0 从配置文件中获取配置信息

        // 设置浏览器在本地的位置  如果是默认的安装位置，则不需要设置
        String firefoxExe = Global.getConfig("firefox.execute");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", firefoxExe);


        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.setHeadless(true);

        // 创建驱动对象；
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

        // 向指定网址发送请求
        driver.get(url);

        // 等待一段时间
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
        logger.info("{{{"+pageSource+"}}}"); // !!! there I get something unexpected.
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(pageSource);


        logger.info("第"+counter.incrementAndGet()+"条数据,"+"页面URL："+url);

        // 关闭驱动
        driver.quit();
        return document;
    }
}
```

I expect the pageSource is rendered so that I can parse the info I need.
like this:

    
    
        
            
            欢迎您，下午好！2019年7月5日 14:46:47
        
    
    ...

but all I get is this(like the raw pageCod):

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script r='m'>document.createElement("section")</script><![endif]-->
    </head>
<body>
<input 
    type="hidden" 
    id="__onload__" 
    name="qLsp0ZDBKQUw_70MRYeJh0bkMr.oUykkn2yj1KXRhPucI8hFjVeSpylsPEgk8gowdN0vGovDjIqFiTyyzVRJo44Js_zY9Bhwx9lUgTQJk8RZnIFQfdLRR4p7VLDx00SPA41uZw4PYM2VDSXuiOeF6KZLDZT2Jmkfn.E_KlSSYwq" 
    value="U17W7zqe6L3khRlEHvj1WG">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the "欢迎您，下午好！" part should goes like html code, but it gets parsed. and I appricate any idea you may give to me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

now this is quite silly, but I make the code wait longer,then I got the correct pageSource.Just change "Thread.sleep(3000)" to "Thread.sleep(5000)", everything will work out fine.

Note that when you deploy your project in a web environment, you gotta consider the delay of network. it is a common issue of all. thank you very much~